# When the user types 'EXIT' the program should close and show all previous inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop, exit

**Objective:** This program asks the user to input as many Social Security Numbers as they desire, it will then validate and make sure it's in the correct format (XXX-XX-XXXX).

If the input is in the correct format it will add the input to the arrays of SSNs. If the format is incorrect, the program will display the message "Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX".

Once the user is done entering SSNs, the user can simply type "EXIT" and the program should display all the SSNs and close the program.

Here's an example of how the program output should look like:

```
*********************SSN Server Storage********************                        
Type 'EXIT' at any moment to close the program                                         
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 615-23-8689                         
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): Hello                               
Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX                                                   
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 951-65-6201                         
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): EXIT                                

The Social Security Numbers you entered are:                                         
615-23-8689                                                                         
951-65-6201
```

**Problem:** When the user types "EXIT" the program does not display all previous SSNs and close after. What am I doing wrong?

**Subclass:**

```
package SSNServerStorage;

public class SSNArray
{
    private String[] SSNNumber;
    private int arrayCount;

    public SSNArray(){
        SSNNumber = new String[300];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public SSNArray(int arraySize){
        SSNNumber = new String[arraySize];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public String[] getSSNNumber(){
        return SSNNumber;
    }

    public int getArrayCount(){
        return arrayCount;
    }

    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
        return SSNFormat.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    }

    public String addSSN(String SSNFormat){
        if (validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
            return SSNNumber[arrayCount++] = SSNFormat;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str = "\nThe Social Security Numbers you entered are:\n";
        for(int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++)
            str += SSNNumber[x] + "\n";
        return str;
    }        
}
```

**Mainclass:**

```
package SSNServerStorage;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static javafx.application.Platform.exit;

public class SSNArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SSNArray SSNArrayObject = new SSNArray();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*********************SSN Server Storage********************");
        System.out.println("Type 'EXIT' at any moment to close the program\n");

        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            System.out.print("Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): ");
            String SSNNumber = input.next();

            if(input.equals("EXIT")){
                System.out.print(SSNArrayObject.toString());
                exit();                
            }else if(SSNArrayObject.validateSSNNumber(SSNNumber)){
                SSNArrayObject.addSSN(SSNNumber);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX");      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(input.equals("EXIT")){
```

This should be

```
if(SSNNumber.equals("EXIT")){
```

By the way, the Java naming convention is to have variable names always start with a lowercase letter. I recommend naming your variable `ssnNumber` instead. Or, even better, I'd rename `input` to `scanner` and then rename `SSNNumber` to `input` to more clearly reflect these variables' purposes.

Comment: Thank you that really helped. I know my exit(); is inside the while loop, what would I do so the program ends there and doesn't loop back to asking the user to input their SSN number. Would I have to use do, while?

Comment: Change `exit();` to `break;` or `return;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `javafx.application.Platform.exit()` method where [System.exit(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) should be used.

A suggestion here is to set `run=false` if input is `EXIT` and you could print `SSNArrayObject` outside the loop. The next step is that the application would exit by itself.